# Explanation of the Nambu-Goto action and calculus needed for a beginner to learn

Tags: string-theory, education

I have recently started trying to learn String Theory, but haven't learnt calculus - I know this probably isn't a good idea, but I decided to learn each part as I go. I'm partly using [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/string-theory/), and have come to the Nambu-Goto action.

Please could someone explain to me what is going on here and what I need to learn to understand it:

$$S=-\frac {T_0}c \int d\tau d\sigma \sqrt {\biggl( {\frac {\partial \vec X} {\partial \tau} \cdot {\frac {\partial \vec X} {\partial \sigma}}}\biggl)^2-\biggl( \frac {\partial \vec X} {\partial \tau} \biggl)^2 \biggl( \frac {\partial \vec X} {\partial \sigma} \biggl)^2}.$$

Comment: What kind of understanding are you looking for? Do you simply want to know what the variables mean? Do you want to know how the action as a concept relates to the rest of string theory? Do you want to be able to actually apply/use this action?

Comment: You need to understand: what a derivative is and what an integral is; what a parameterized surface is; enough Special Relativity to understand Lorentz invariance, spacetime, worldlines and worldsheets; why this is the area of the string’s worldsheet; what an action is. However, I don’t recommend this learn-it-as-you-need-it approach. I don’t think it will give you a sufficiently deep understanding.

Comment: Start by learning calculus... else it’s like “I’ve started to try to learn to fly jet fighters but I don’t know how to fly.”

Comment: After I voted to close this question as “too broad”, but before it reached five close votes and got closed, I decided to attempt an answer. Unfortunately, I then forgot to retract my close vote. I’ve now voted to reopen in case others want to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's talk generally about actions and about calculus.

There are a variety of ways to specify the dynamics of any system. Modern physics often prefers to use an [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) rather than explicit equations of motion. The action functional integrates an arbitrarily-imagined evolution of a system between an initial state and a final state and produces a single number, the action for that particular dynamical path. (By "path" I mean "way of evolving the entire system", not "trajectory of one particle".) This number is a physical quantity with the dimensions of action, which are energy times time; in SI units, action is measured in joule-seconds.

As the system evolves, its dynamical variables are constantly changing, so the action functional typically involves [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), which in calculus express the rate at which something changes. And since the action is computed from the evolution over a finite amount of time, it also involves an [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral). Integration is the process in calculus by which you add up an infinite number of infinitesimal quantities.

In classical mechanics, the equations of motion can be found from the action functional via the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). (Relevant math: [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations).) The basic idea is that the value of the action doesn't change to a first approximation when you vary the system's path slightly from the path that satisfies the equations of motion.

In quantum mechanics, the [probability amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude) for the system to evolve from an initial state to a final state is proportional to the sum of $e^{iS/\hbar}$ over *all possible paths*, where $S$ is the action for a path and $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant. This is Feynman's [path integral formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) of quantum mechanics.

So, to summarize, knowing the action of a system tells you both its classical dynamics and its quantum dynamics.

Now let's talk about strings. (By the way, I am *not* a string theorist.)

A string is a one-dimensional object that lives in spacetime. A particular point on the string can be specified using a continuous parameter $\sigma$. You could think of it as running from 0 at one end to 1 at the other end of the string. If the string didn't move, you could talk about the location in spacetime of a particular point on the string as $\vec{X}(\sigma)$. (Here the arrow indicates a spacetime [four-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector), not a spatial three-vector.) But strings do move around, just like point particles do, so we write $\vec{X}(\sigma, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is a kind of proper time for the string.

You can think of $\vec{X}(\sigma, \tau)$ as the surface swept out in spacetime by the string as it evolves. This is called the string's worldsheet. This is analogous to the [worldline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) of a point particle moving through spacetime.

The relativistic action of a point particle is simply proportional the [Lorentz-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar) length of its worldline, measured using the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) of spacetime. By analogy, the relativistic action of a string is simply proportional to the Lorentz-invariant *area* of its worldsheet, measured using the same metric. When the action is Lorentz-invariant, the equations of motion are form-invariant under Lorentz transformations.

The integral in the Nambu-Goto action represents the area of the worldsheet. If you learn how to compute areas of surfaces in calculus, this will become more obvious. The relevant math is the [first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form).

The multiplicative factors involve the string tension $T_0$ and the speed of light $c$. You can check that a tension (which is just a force) times an area, divided by a speed, has the right dimensions to be an action.

The thirteen Wikipedia links I’ve provided will let you pursue more self-study of the relevant physics and mathematics.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. I know that it would be better to study each topic conventionally and _then_ bring them together, but I've found this way more enjoyable in the past